# test if two Binomial distribution are significantly different

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have two groups of people.
Group one with 16 choosing 1 and 33 choosing 2.
Group two with 10 choosing 1 and 49 choosing 2.
I assume they both follows Binomial distribution. So how can I found out if they are significant different from each other?
(I have used nonparametric method to see they are neither randomly picked. Besides, I think t-test is infeasible in this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a likelihood-ratio test.

There is an example which corresponds exactly to your problem on the wikipedia page :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test

The correspondance with your question is: Group 1/2 = Coin 1/2, and 1/2 = Heads/Tails.